# Элемент массива, повторяющийся наибольшее количество раз

Tags: массивы, vb.net, алгоритм

Нужно найти элемент массива, повторяющийся наибольшее количество раз. Тип массива Integer, массив отсортирован. Подойдет код на любом языке, кроме ассемблеров и непроцедурных.

Comment: Отсортировать, затем посчитать количество по каждому значению с запоминанием наибольшего. Можно подсчитывать количество вхождений в словаре (реализующем IDictionary), затем найти наибольший. Масса вариантов.

Comment: Буду благодарен, если предоставите приблизительный код.

Comment: Алгоритм я уже понял.

Comment: А если максимальное число раз повторяются несколько значений?

Comment: То вывод 2 - ух значений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте возможности LINQ в .NET. Код на C#, на VB.NET должно быть аналогично.

```
int[] values = { 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2 };

int result = (from v in values select v).GroupBy(g => g).OrderByDescending(o => o.Count()).FirstOrDefault().Key;
```

Answer (score 1):

На С++. Шаблонная функция getmaxrepeat, возвращающая вектор со значениями элементов, имеющих максимальное число повторений. Функция comp_pair - вспомогательная, в C++11 ее можно было бы сделать лямбда-функцией

```
template <typename T> static  inline bool comp_pair (const pair<T, int>& a1, const pair<T, int>& a2) {
    return a1.second < a2.second;
}
template <typename T, typename N> vector<T> getmaxrepeat (const T* arr, N n) {
    map<T, N> mc;
    for (N i = 0; i < n; ++i) ++mc[arr[i]]; 
    N maxrep = max_element (mc.begin(), mc.end(), comp_pair<T>)->second;    
    vector<T> vec;  
    for (typename map<T, N>::iterator it = mc.begin(); it != mc.end(); ++it) 
        if (it->second == maxrep) vec.push_back (it->first);
    return vec; 
}
```

Comment: Для меня - сложновато, тем более не зная C++